# Perl replacing special characters

Tags: perl

I wanted to replace a "_" with a correct guessed letter in hangman Perl program I was creating. I tried many tutorials. It broke the original string in a variety of different ways, such as making the whole string disappear, or make half of it disappear.

The main code is extremely long, so I will only do the part I am having trouble with.

```
my $old = '_ _ _'; # Gives player sense of how many letters the word is
my $correctGuess = "a"; # Correct guess
my $new = $old =~ s/_/$correctGuess/r; # Replaces the letter
print($old, "\n"); # Prints old
print($new); # Prints new string
```

As you can see, the correct guess is a. This is not really the code I am using, as I have a  and an if statement that checks it.
However, it replaces the first "*". How do I specify which "*" to replace? Thank you.

Comment: Please provide more detail. What does the string look like before, what do you want it to look like after, and what exact code have you tried?

Comment: You can use `substr($new, $index, 1, 'a');` or `substr($new, $index, 1) = 'a';` to assign a character to a specific position in a string. Finding the appropriate position is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thanks! But one more question, is $index the length of the string, and $new the old string?

Comment: Perhaps you intended `my $new = $old =~ s/_/$correctGuess/g;` -- it will replace all `_` with a letter stored in `$correctGuess`.

Comment: Got too confused and gave up. Just printed the location of the letter instead of showing it with a "_ _ _".

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to start with the secret word, and replace the unguessed letters with `_`.

```
my $secret = "Just another Perl hacker";

my %guesses;
my $num_guesses = 0;
while (1) {
   my $public = $secret =~ s/([a-zA-Z])/ $guesses{uc($1)} ? $1 : "_" /erg;

   say $public;

   if ($public !~ /_/) {
      say "Success after $num_guesses guesses!";
      last;
   }

   # TODO: Check against maximum number of guesses allowed here.

   my @gueses = sort keys %guesses;
   # TODO: Display previous guesses and the number of remaining guesses.

   # TODO: Display prompt here.
   my $letter = ...;
   if ($letter !~ /^[a-zA-Z]\z/) {
      warn("Not a letter!\n");
      next;
   }

   my $uc_letter = uc($letter);

   if ($guesses{$uc_letter}) {
      warn("Already guessed \"$uc_letter\"!\n");
      next;
   }

   ++$guesses{$uc_letter};
   ++$num_guesses;
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you, now I decided to not give up on that. Thanks again!